# SignalR in multiple instances in Azure

Tags: asp.net, azure, signalr, azureservicebus

I'd like to use Azure to host my web application, for instance CloudService web role or Azure Websites, inside the application I use SignalR to connect client and server.

Since I scaled two instances for my web roles, it seems I came across a very common problem, the SignalR could not find the correct original instance. The client JavaScript said it was already started, but the server hub `OnConnected` event randomly not raised, so were the server methods which intended to be called by clients, all these strange issues happened randomly.

Once I changed the instance to be one, all the problems gone. So can anyone explain what happened when the client call server method, why sometimes the server seems not response properly?

I found the [post](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/performance-and-scaling/scaleout-with-windows-azure-service-bus), can Azure Service Bus solve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you need to use the azure service bus. Otherwise the connections are stored in memory on the given server and the other server will know nothing about them. Once you create the service bus, just reference it in the startup class.

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Trace.TraceInformation("SignalR Startup > Configurtion start");
    // Any connection or hub wire up and configuration should go here
    string connectionString = "XXX";
    GlobalHost.DependencyResolver.UseServiceBus(connectionString, "TopicName");

    ...
}
```

You will also need to get a reference to the context in each of your hub methods:

```
  var context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<HubName>();
```

It's easy peasy :)

Comment: Thanks, I am still puzzled about one thing: does the connection exist only at the original instance or a new connection created as the instance response the client call?

Comment: The connection is spawned from the client... a client id is generated and that client id is used for communication until the user changes pages (in the case of the JavaScript client). The id will be used for all messages sent to that client. If the user changes pages, a new client id will be generated.

Comment: So assume the connection was stored at instance A(without using ServiceBus), then the client call server method, instance B took the place, does instance B will create new hub instance to response the request or simply it cannot response at all?

Comment: It should be able to respond fine although it would likely have a different connection id (they are generated on server). SignalR is stateless and there is no session involved. The issue is that the collections of users are separate unless you use the backplane. If you for instance said to broadcast a message from Server A to all users, all users tracked on Server A would get the message but not server B. If you tried to send a message to a specific user id and they happened to be on diff server, they would not receive it. You have to use the backplane.